# Indoor mapping data structure

Tags: openlayers-2, indoor

I wanted to know, are there any formats/data structures made specifically for indoor mapping? I have looked at OpenLayers + GeoJSON however:

1. How will I sync up the coordinates of my local map and the ones GeoJSON uses? (I think this is done by georeferencing the map if I understood correctly)
2. How will I handle different floors and manage routing (when I eventually come to that) if GeoJSON has no support for that?

That's why I wanted to know if there are any specific solution that would be beneficial for making an interactive indoor map with support for multiple floors and routing!

I've already looked at a bunch of questions which helped me a lot, but I haven't found a good answer to my questions.

Comment: Take a look at http://clement-lagrange.github.io/osmtools-indoor/#lat=50.64494&lon=3.07284&z=20 for indoor mapping and floors

Comment: Thanks, that would mean users would have to zoom in to the building and look over it. Is there something that's more focused on the floor plans of the building itself? Also I don't see that project using any specific format for storing data about rooms etc which I'd like to load dynamically.